# WordPress child theme not overwriting changes

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two themes in my WordPress installation, `theme1` and `theme1-child` (set as active).

There is a part of the `theme1` that I want to edit, `theme1/inc/templates/post-meta.php`

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme1_entry_date' ) ) :
function theme1_entry_date( $echo = true ) {
    if ( has_post_format( array( 'chat', 'status' ) ) )
        $format_prefix = _x( '%1$s on %2$s', '1: post format name. 2: date', 'theme1' );
    else
        $format_prefix = '%2$s';


    $date = sprintf( __( ' on ', 'theme1' ) . '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'theme1' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( sprintf( $format_prefix, get_post_format_string( get_post_format() ), get_the_date() ) )
    );

    if ( $echo )
        echo $date;

    return $date;
}
endif;
```

`style.css`

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme1 Child
Theme URI: http://www.url.com
Description: This is a child theme for Theme1.
Author: Author
Author URI: http: //www.url.com
Template: theme1
Version: 1.0
*/

@import url("../theme1/style.css");

div.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs{display:none !important;}
html body .resp-tabs-container {margin-bottom: 30px;}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    html body div.resp-tab-content {
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
}
```

So I have re-created this file with the amendments in: `theme1-child/inc/templates/post-meta.php`, however the amendments aren't shown.

Any ideas to why this isn't picking up the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to paste **theme1_entry_date** function into your child theme **functions.php** file.

Thanks

Comment: I've done that, and it appears to work, so I should add all my changes to the functions.php, and do away with the post-meta.php?

Comment: If you want to override parent theme PHP functions, then yes. Please mark as correct if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have bugs in style.css file placed in child template?

Comment: It's just blank, I am only trying to do this one change. Both functions.php and style.css are blank.

Comment: See https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes - you have to create style.css with specific content.